# How can I open files in any directory in my computer when using Jupyter Lab?

Tags: jupyter-lab

After launching the Jupyter Lab interface, I tried to open a Python file using the `File -> Open` menu. Yet no matter what I enter for a path in my PC, it cannot be reached. Does Jupyter Lab impose any restriction upon gaining access to a PC's directory? And how can I open files from any directory I desire if there is any workaround?

Here is a screenshot of the "Open" dialogue.

[image: JupyterLab Open Path dialogue]

Answer (score 7):

The JupyterLab root is usually where JupyterLab was started from.

For example if we start JupyterLab as follows:

```
$ cd ~/year
$ jupyter lab
```

then the JupyterLab root is `~/year`.

There is a command-line option to select a different directory.
For example, if we do the following,

```
$ cd ~/season
$ jupyter lab --notebook-dir ~/year
```

then the JupyterLab root is again `~/year`.

The relative path for a file `~/year/month/day.txt`
would then be `month/day.txt` --- so enter that
in the "Open Path" dialogue and it should open.

I find the grey hint `/path/relative/to/jlab/root` in
the "Path" field of the "Open File" dialogue misleading.
In my opinion it should be `path/relative/to/jlab/root`
without the initial slash.

Regarding restrictions, the restriction is that
JupyterLab can only access files which are inside
the root directory determined when starting it.

So in the example, we cannot access files outside `~/year`.